# JSON : Accessing specific leaf, in variable depth branches

Tags: javascript, json

So, I have a JSON object built like this (see below), for which I'm trying to access the "layers" leaf that is not of "layerSection" type. I know I could use something like myJsonObject.layers[0].layers[0].layers[0].layers[0].name, but the thing is, I never know how "deep" the leaf is gonna be in its branch. Sometimes, there's no "layerSection" layers at all, but sometimes, there could be a dozen. (or more... there's actually no limit to the number of "layerSection")

To make things even worst, there are also some "empty" branches, with a few "layerSection" layers, without any "normal" layers at the end of it. Those need to be ignored.

And finally, once I get to the leaf, I need to know how deep it's actually is. In other words, I need to know how many "layerSection" I had to go through to get to the leaf.

I'm not used to deal with more complex JSON objects like this. Any help would be really apreciated.

Thanks a million !

Here's the json object :

```
{
  "version": "1.6.1",
  "timeStamp": 1592062633.423,
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": 13,
      "index": 10,
      "type": "layerSection",
      "name": "Group 1",
      "layers": [
        {
          "id": 15,
          "index": 9,
          "type": "layerSection",
          "name": "Group 2",
          "layers": [
            {
              "id": 17,
              "index": 8,
              "type": "layerSection",
              "name": "Group 3",
              "layers": [
                {
                  "id": 12,
                  "index": 7,
                  "type": "adjustmentLayer",
                  "name": "The leaf I am trying to get to",
                  "visible": true,
                  "clipped": true,
                  "adjustment": {
                    "presetKind": "presetKindDefault",
                    "class": "curves"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this JSON structure as a tree data structure. There are some ways to get the leaf nodes of a tree, here I suggest using Depth-First Search to get the leaf layer names.

Suppose you define a leaf layer is a layer which has no more children layers, that's when you return the name of the layer. This function returns all the leaf layer names in your JSON structure along with how deep they are in the JSON.

```js
function getLeafLayerNames(data, depth = 0) {
    if (!data.layers) return [{ name: data.name, depth }]

    const names = []
    for (const layer of data.layers) {
        const n = getLeafLayerNames(layer, depth + 1) // DFS recursive, depth increases by 1
        names.push(...n)
    }
    return names.filter(n => n)
}
```

At last, I use a filter to select only *defined* layer names. An *undefined* value can be found when a leaf layer has no property `name` in it.